# How to place JDBC Drivers as System Dependencies in SBT Projects Scala/Play Projects in Dev Mode

Tags: java, scala, jdbc, playframework, sbt

I have a bunch of dependencies, such as JDBC Drivers, from vendors like Oracle, and Microsoft, which are not on a Public Artifact Repository.

Everytime I want those dependencies to be available while running my Play Application in **Dev Mode**, I have to put those jars in `lib` folder(within the play project)

Those drivers are supposed to vary from Customer to Customer, and in some phases of the project we need a Oracle one, some other phase, 2 drivers.

Another point is that, we have multiple Play Applications that we use those drivers, and have to manually place them within the `lib` folder

How can I avoid this??

I need those jars in the classpath for when I am saying from the command line:

```
sbt run "play-project" -Dhttp.port=9001
```

> **Maybe there is some play parameter that I can also pass an additional
>   classpath.**

I am using Play 2.4 and Scala 2.11.7

Comment: what are you using to build a project?

Comment: Sbt as a build tool

Comment: I would check the docs on how it works with repos. It can read maven repos. I would install those dependencies locally (maven) then point sbt to that maven repo

Comment: Note that Microsoft *has* [recently open-sourced the MS SQL server JDBC driver](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jdbcteam/2016/11/17/open-source-jdbc-maven/) and put it up on maven - [I think it's this one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc), but do double-check.

Comment: I need those jars in the classpath, for when it is running...

Comment: Hi @efekcitive   - I think the key point here is that I want to have those jars available in the classpath in Dev Mode, in other words when I run from the command line with "sbt run", in the root project folder.

Comment: Apparently sbt can read poms but for definitions not repositories. So I would check Ivy. I would assume that sbt uses the dependencies for building as well as for running It seems that you need a dependency manager in place

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two solutions:

1. Add your specifics jar files in a common folder and reference that one from your build file. You should add some environment properties or some configurable way to allow other people from your team to configure the jars location.
2. Create a private maven or ivy repository that contains the specific jars. It could be as simple as a http server with the files and the correct directory structure. This allows you to internally distribute the jar file without having people to configure specific folders on their machines.

For the first solution, from [SBT documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html), you should just add those jars in your unmanaged classpath, with in your `build.sbt` file a line like:

```
unmanagedJars in Compile := (file("/my_common_path") ** "*.jar").classpath
```

For the second solution, just have a look at [sbt's resolver documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html)

Comment: I edited my comment, the proposed line should be added in your build.sbt file.